# Angular project building locally but not in gitlab

Tags: angular, gitlab

I'm attempting to automatically deploy an angular application and while I can build the project locally with --prod, as soon as I attempt to build it in gitlab I run into the issue that some (but not all) of my components cannot be found. My IDE finds all of them with no issues.

I've attempted re-ordering the commits, starting with a fresh ubuntu container, changing from double to single quotes in my imports, etc.

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AssetFilesComponent } from './asset-files/asset-files.component';
import { GeomapComponent } from './geomap/geomap.component';
import { AssetTimeseriesViewerComponent } from './asset-timeseries/assettimeseries/asset-timeseries-viewer.component';
import { KpiComponent } from './kpi/kpi.component';
import { EventsComponent } from './events/events.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'geomap', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'geomap', component: GeomapComponent },
  { path: 'asset-files', component: AssetFilesComponent },
  { path: 'kpis', component: KpiComponent },
  { path: 'asset-timeseries', component: AssetTimeseriesViewerComponent },
  { path: 'events', component: EventsComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

```
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { AssetFilesComponent } from './asset-files/asset-files.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { GeomapComponent } from './geomap/geomap.component';
import { ChartModule } from './chart/chart.module';
import { KpiComponent } from './kpi/kpi.component';
import { EventsComponent } from './events/events.component';

import { AssetTimeseriesChartModule } from './asset-timeseries/asset-timeserieschart.module';


/* App Root */
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

/* Routing Module */
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

/* Building Blocks */
import { BuildingBlocksModule } from 'building-blocks';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    GeomapComponent,
    AssetFilesComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    KpiComponent,
    EventsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BuildingBlocksModule,
    ChartModule,
    AssetTimeseriesChartModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The message I get from gitlab looks like this:

```
Hash: 66dd67383385c874df28
Time: 89852ms
chunk {0} runtime.26209474bfa8dc87a77c.js (runtime) 1.41 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.01ecbc0fcff9207e8cde.js (main) 128 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.a723c36635c3a098c2aa.js (polyfills) 130 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} styles.350a9b101128c3dd4672.css (styles) 960 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.9399614690f9a0599e1e.js (scripts) 2.31 MB [entry] [rendered]

ERROR in app/app.module.ts(36,5): Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
  Could not resolve ./kpi/kpi.component relative to [object Object]..
src/app/app-routing.module.ts(5,48): error TS2307: Cannot find module './asset-timeseries/assettimeseries/asset-timeseries-viewer.component'.
src/app/app-routing.module.ts(6,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module './kpi/kpi.component'.
src/app/app-routing.module.ts(7,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module './events/events.component'.
src/app/app.module.ts(10,29): error TS2307: Cannot find module './chart/chart.module'.
src/app/app.module.ts(11,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module './kpi/kpi.component'.
src/app/app.module.ts(12,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module './events/events.component'.
src/app/app.module.ts(14,44): error TS2307: Cannot find module './asset-timeseries/asset-timeserieschart.module'.
```

Like I said, the modules are certainly there, right next to the ones that angular doesn't complain about. I'm building locally on a windows 10 machine and attempting to build in an ubuntu container. I'm not sure if that is making a difference here.

Thanks for any help.